# Invariant Violation: The Navigaion prop is missing for this navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

i'm new to react-native i want my app to navigate to another screen and use this code

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqgQr.png)
i got this error.
[error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkpZn.png)

i have do this to my projects

1. > npm install --save react-navigaion
2. > npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
3. > react-native link

And i run my project.

> react-native run-android

Answer (score 2):

First, I would recommend putting your code in your question. That would make things a little easier.

You're missing `createAppContainer` HOC. You should export your component at the bottom of your file and wrap it in `createAppContainer()`.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html#creating-a-stack-navigator

Comment: Also, do you have your code in a remote repo that I could look at?